# Firebase NoSQL database sample

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have recently been learning Firebase for my salon app. I successfully use Firebase for authentication (Facebook, Google, Email) and now I am planning to continue to use Firebase Realtime DB for my app.

My app will cover member registration, reservation, services list, employees and transactions (treatment). Unfortunately, I am stuck and confuse at creating my data structure. I have no experience in NoSQL and I also could not find any complete db/data structure sample of one app (especially one that include transaction like e-commerce).

Please help give me any samples if you have or know so I can have better picture for my app. Thank you.

Comment: The best place to look at is the official docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: Hi Goofy_Phie. Have you seen the [Firebase Database for SQL Developers series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfenWGeHarE) on Youtube yet? :)

Comment: In addition to the links already given, I always recommend this non-Firebase specific article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: @ramden been there and they only give snippet code

Comment: @AL. it seems a good link, i am gonna load all the series first, bad internet in my country, i should wait around 30 min to watch 4 min video at 360p , it's very sad but i hope i can find answers in that links. thanks.

Comment: @AL. i watched the video but the fourth series (common query lesson) was kinda heartbreaking, especially at no.8 cases, noSql can't execute simple query like "select * from users where age=28 and location='berlin'"  , they told us to add more data to data structure age_location, what the... , what kind of hack is that.. ,  how can we even make good app with so many limitation like that.